# Button to send email in NetSuite workflow

Tags: task, workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I need help creating a "Submit Feedback" Button that essentially, would email the admin the text of the feedback the user submits. If I can do this with a workflow, I would prefer that. However, if we need to create a SuiteScript, that's OK.

I need to know how to get the button to stay on the task at all times so the user can always see it no matter what. Moreover, I then need to have the feedback sent to the admin via email. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Workflow: Event Definition>On Create and On View or Update (to make sure the button always appears)

State 1: Action > Add Button (Trigger on Before Record Load)

State 2: Action > Send Email Transition: From > State 1, To > State 2, Execute On Button > Choose button created in State 1

Once you have set all the required fields for these steps, this should work.  Let me know if you need anything clarified.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I just noticed I did not mention this in my OP. I need the button to either create a popup for the user to enter text into. Or, open a new tab in NS (or even possibly and external link) so, they can fill out a form to send feedback. How would the workflow change per these requirements?

Comment: When I set up and tested it, I used the {message} field to put some test 'feedback' into and inserted {message} in the email body under the Send Email action.  If you want to keep the message field for something else, you could set a custom field to store the feedback message.  Users would just have to fill that in before they click the button.  As far as creating a popup to prompt the user for the feedback message, I think that would require scripting.