# Netsuite - Send Email Action Button Not Working

Tags: netsuite

I am working on a workflow that creates a button to "Email All" that emails the customer and then the list of emails in a text field on the invoice. I know the Send Email Action works on its own when tested and the button can be created. i can't to sew them together so that clicking the button performs the action.

I have the workflow set up this way:

State 1
Action Add Button on Before record Load with label "Email All"

Transition from state 1 to state 2. Transition on Entry, and Execute on clicking button in state 1

State 2
Send Email Action. Trigger on Entry
Recipient = Customer > E-Mail. CC {custbodycustbody_cc_emails_to_include} (custom text field)

I'm a bit new to workflows and can't seem to nail this last part. There was a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526756/button-to-send-email-in-netsuite-workflow)

but the steps did not produce the action. The log seems to only show the Add Button. No other errors.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the workflow logs, did you check the "Show Rejected Actions" option.  I think there might be an issue with the CC field.  If I recall correctly, it does not support field ids there.

Comment: I did check that. The CC works. I had tested it as a standalone workflow and it went through.